# Proper regex for this URL

Tags: python, regex

What regex would I use to get urls that follow this pattern:

> 'https://www.facebook.com/' + 'some text' + 'browser'

Meaning that it starts with the facebook url, has some text which varies, and then has the word 'browser' at the end?

Thanks!

Comment: What regex have you tried?

Comment: I actually tried something very similar to this. For some reason my script isn't working so maybe the error lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r'https://www\.facebook\.com/.*browser'
```

`.` is a regex metacharacter meaning "any single character", so the literal periods have to be escaped with backslashes. `*` means "any number of matches for the previous thing", so `.*` means "any number of arbitrary characters". The `r` in front of the string marks it as a raw string literal, so backslashes are processed by the regex engine instead of the Python parser.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is `r'https://www\.facebook\.com/.*browser$'` , because the word 'browser' is at the end.

Comment: Ah! Okay, maybe that was it.